# VB6 Verify digital signature?

Tags: vb6, com-interop, digital-signature, digital-certificate

**TL;DR:** How do you verify the digital signature of a COM interop assembly from VB6?

**Full question:** I have a legacy VB6 project which needs to call some .net code (these requirements are a must). We think the best way to do this is with COM interop. However we don't want any hackers switching out the COM assembly for a fake one. We think the best way to guard against this is to digitally sign the COM assembly. If this is the best way to go (please say if otherwise), how do I verfiy the digital signature of the COM assembly fromVB6?

I've tried googling but all I get is 3rd party libraries or implementations for verifying specific signing algorithms. Surely there must be a simpler way?

Thanks!

Comment: This question has been there for a while, I thought I could help a bit. By digital signature, do you mean an Authenticode signature ? If you (or your company) have an Authenticode signing certificate, you could sign your assembly, and then whenever you need to load the assembly you check before-hand the signature & certificate through the crypto API. There's a code sample by Microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323809) that shows how to use [CryptQueryObject()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380264) to retrieve information on an Authenticode-signed file.

Comment: [continued] Depending on how far you want to go through possible checks, you'll have to store in your calling executable the public key of your certificate, or maybe just its serial number + issuer, etc. Then you'll have to protect somehow that info, to make sure a hacker doesn't swap both (COM assembly + certificate/public key within caller). It's mostly a game of hide and seek; you'll have to decide how many layers of protection you wrap this in, to make it harder for the hacker to pull it off while at the same time make sure checking(+loading) the COM doesn't take forever.